# Insert next records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have requirement like, I have to insert the records whenever for one `BID`, one `SID`, if the `execdate` and `stopbilldate` exist, then I need to insert new record with `NULL` as `Stopbilldate`
sample example is as follows:

```
Sno BID     SID LID     Comapny Execdate    StopBilldate
5   BLDG100 C   6500    Cole    1/5/2012    5/29/2012
6   BLDG100 C   000000  Vacant  5/30/2012   NULL
```

Comment: So to clarify your question, you're looking for a method whereby every time a `StopBilldate` is filled in for a row, a new row needs to be created for the same `BID` and `SID`, with default values "000000" for `LID`, "Vacant" for `Company`, the next day _after_ the previous value `StopBillDate` in `Execdate`, and null in `StopBilldate`. Is this correct? That could be accomplished with a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [`TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on your table. A trigger is a kind of stored procedure that will execute when an event occurs.

Here is a sample of what you could place on your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trg_yourTable]
   ON  [yourTable]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    INSERT INTO yourTable (bid, sid, lid, company, execdate, stopbilldate)
    SELECT i.bid, i.sid, 0, 'Vacant', DATEADD(day, 1, i.stopbilldate), null
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.bid is not null
        and i.sid is not null
END
```

When you `INSERT` data in the table, this will run and `INSERT` the additional row that you want added to the table.